# angular js ng-include not linking to scope/controller function

Tags: angularjs

need some guru advice. I have created a simple off-menu canvas as you can see in the code found in the following plnkr. The issue is I have used ng-include for navbar, which has the toggle switch that interacts with the main scope.

The problem is the navbar is shown but when I try to click on the toggle button it does not work. Please plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/QF5rEv

If I replace the navbar.html contents and put it in the main page it works fine.

I appreciate if anyone can tell me what is going on? And the work around? Thanks in advance!

This is my code found in plnkr:

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.11"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <!--navLeft Menu-->
  <div class="navLeft" ng-class="navLeft?'navLeft-on':'navLeft-off'">
    <div ng-show="navLeft">
      <ul>Nav goes here</ul>
    </div>
    <!--/Nav div show-->
  </div>
  <!--/Nav Left-->

  <!--navRight Menu-->
  <div class="navRight" ng-class="navRight?'navRight-on':'navRight-off'">
    <div ng-show="navRight">
      hi
    </div>
    <!--/Nav div show-->
  </div>
  <!--/Nav right-->

  <!--Canvas where header, content and footer sits-->
  <div class="canvas" ng-class="navClick()">
    <!--changes class of canvas in accordance to NavLeft or NavRight is on-->
    <div ng-include="'navbar.html'"></div>

    <!--content-->
    <div class="content">
      Content goes here
    </div>
    <!--/content-->

  </div>
  <!--/canvas-->


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-include creating new scope so to access MainCtrl scope you can use $parent in your navbar.html

```
ng-click="$parent.navLeft=!$parent.navLeft"
```

please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/vRoBPzjDSjbE7om5zAKn?p=preview

or change create new object

```
  $scope.nav = {

    navLeft:false,//default navLeft menu off
    navRight:false//default navRight menu off

  };
```

and after that you can use `nav.navLeft` in your navbar

please see here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/PQOeT61mjZdDWwSbjlyQ?p=preview

but you should consider to split your controller into smaller parts ie: content, navbar and communicate between them using service

Comment: Thanks a million, that worked! Yes you are right about service part, still quite new to angularjs, I will check it out.

Comment: I'm actually looking into services now and trying to wrap my head around it. Are you able to give some further insight on how this app would be benefit from service? Really appreciate any comments

Comment: @KaTech please see here https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers